# Complex Analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am struggling with showing that the image of $e^{1/z}$ is all of $\mathbb{C}$ except $0$.  I know that there is an essential singularity at $z=0$ and the principal part of the Laurent Series contains an infinite number of terms.  I also know that Picard's theorem says that in a small neighborhood of an isolated essential singularity, an analytic function assumes every finite complex value, with one exception, an infinite number of times.  I'm just not sure how to piece everything together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have it with Picard's Theorem.  The first thing is to see that $f(z) = e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$.  Recall that an essential singularity is one that has infinitely many negative powers in the Laurent expansion.  Then apply Picard's theorem:  In any neighborhood of the essential singularity at $z=0$, the function $f$ attains all values in $\mathbb{C}$ with possibly one exception, which in this case is $z=0$.

It should be clear that $f(z)$ never equals $0$.  So then we're basically done:  Picard implies that in any neighborhood of the essential singularity at $z=0$, $f$ attains all values of $\mathbb{C}$ except for $0$.  So, the range of $f$ is all of $\mathbb{C}$ except for $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Picard is overkill, to put it mildly. The function $1/z$ is a bijection from $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ onto $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}.$ Since $e^z$ maps $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ onto $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\},$ so does $e^{1/z}.$